# have a problem on Kotlin Jetpack Compose function

Tags: api, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

This "Marker" list is used in the "Google Map()" method. My problem is that the variable "filteredMarkers" does not recognise the term "title". This is the error:
Unresolved reference: title

```
var search by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val markers = listOf(
        Marker(
            position = LatLng(x, y),
            title = "Park 1",
            snippet = "Zone"
        ),
        Marker(
            position = LatLng(x, y),
            title = "Park 2",
            snippet = "Zone"
        ),
        Marker(
            position = LatLng(x, y),
            title = "Park 3",
            snippet = "Zone"
        )
    )
val filteredMarkers = markers.filter { marker ->
        marker.title.contains(search, ignoreCase = true)
    }
```

I've tried this implementation but it doesn't work either:

```
val filteredMarkers = markers.filter {
        it.title.contains(search, ignoreCase = true)
    }
```

Comment: You might have imported the wrong Marker.